# getstream.io NotificationDropdown displaying empty

Tags: javascript, getstream-io

I've set up Stream in my app, and a NotificationDropdown, initially it said "no data to display" (which was correct).  but now after adding an activity it just seems to break and show nothing.

The token a received from using the ruby gem

```
<StreamApp
  apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STREAM_API_KEY}
  appId={process.env.REACT_APP_STREAM_APP_ID}
  token={process.env.REACT_APP_STREAM_TOKEN
>
  <NotificationDropdown
    notify
  />
</StreamApp>
```

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: do you have any error in the console? if yes, please attach that here

Comment: What verb are you using on your activity? The default Group component only displays verbs of a certain kind: repost, like, follow and comment. Otherwise it will display nothing but it should show you a warning in the console. You can customize this by passing your own component to the Group prop on NotificationDropdown